# How do you develop simple code for Gtk+ 3 touch input?

Tags: touch, gesture, gtk3, gtk#

I've been searching for a little while to investigate whether or not our Gtk+ 3 application (Gtk#, actually, but bound to Gtk+ 3) will be easily convertible to receive touch events rather than mouse clicks. This is pure investigation at the moment since I don't actually *have* a touch screen yet (that's also the reason why I can't easily test my theories).

As far as I can tell, the [Gnome 3 can indeed do this](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/pointer-and-touch-input.html.en) and the documentation that seems relevant is the gesture stuff, found [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/Gestures.html).

I've not been able to find any sample Gtk+ code so I'm *hoping* it's a simple matter of instantiating one of the gesture classes and simply setting it up to deliver events to the main event loop.

Is there anyone with experience with Gtk gestures that can guide me in a simple example? Let's say I have a `DrawableArea` and I want to receive a very simple, single-touch event that gives me an event with the point within the area that was touched.

Once I have that, I should be able to build on it to handle swipes, pinches and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inject pointer events as touch events: they are fundamentally different, and they interact with the gesture recognition state machine that lives inside GTK.

GTK has the ability (for debugging purposes) to emulate touch events via pointer, though obviously it cannot emulate multi-touch events because a pointing device only has one event sequence. If you have a recent version of GTK 3.x, you can use the `GTK_TEST_TOUCHSCREEN` environment variable set to a non-zero value.

If you want to know how to use `GtkGesture` implementations in your own widgets, then I suggest you look at the [GtkGesture](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkGesture.html) API reference, and look at the various types of gestures available, like [GtkGestureSwipe](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkGestureSwipe.html) or [GtkGestureZoom](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkGestureZoom.html). You're supposed to add `GtkGesture` instances to your widget when constructing it, and then catch the signals on the specific gesture when they are recognised.

Comment: ebassi, I'm not sure I understand your point in the first two paragraphs. I wasn't intending to emulate touch events with a pointer, rather I wanted to figure out how to set it up so that touch events could be captured in the main loop. In other words, if a user touched the drawable area, how would I set it up to receive those and what events (signals) would appear on the queue? Or, if that's *not* the way it's done, how is it done?

Comment: You said you don't have a touch device, so I pointed you at the debugging mode that lets you emulate one; if you want to handle touch and touchpad gestures, then you should use the GtkGesture classes that GTK provides.